# Minyan of 9 Israelis and 1 American on first day chol hamoed?

Tags: tefilla, eretz-yisrael

If there were 10 men in Israel, 9 Israelis and 1 American, together in a small shul on the morning of the first day of chol hamoed, would they form a minyan? The question is whether the one person davening the yontif amida can join with the 9 men who are davening the chol hamoed amida. Why or why not?

Comment: First day of Chol HaMoed for whom? Where are they physically? I can't imagine how they possibly aren't a Minyan. The question is just what can they do with that Minyan. They can certainly bentch with God's name in the Zimmun for instance.

Comment: The American is in Israel? I assume it's 1st day Israeli Hol Hamo'ed?

Comment: The general rule in all these cases is just do your own thing privately and don't do anything outwardly against what is going on around you. If you're doing it right, no one else should know you are keeping a different number of days of Yom Tov. Why wouldn't that just apply here like usual?

Comment: @DoubleAA Are you saying Zimmun  and minyan have the same laws? Source?

Comment: @YehudaW Mishna Megillah Chapter 4. Why would you think otherwise?

Comment: @DoubleAA Source for: "The general rule "?

Comment: @YehudaW Mishna Pesachim Chapter 4.

Comment: @DoubleAA  A page reference would be better than a chapter reference. Can you provide page references for the two chapters you just cited?

Comment: @YehudaW Page in what? It's Mishnayot Megillah 4:3 and Pesachim 4:1.

Comment: See Kitzur Yalkut Yosef 496:26. R' Ovadya says no -- http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_01355_part_26.html#HtmpReportNum0005_L2

Comment: @DoubleAA "Page in what? "  In the Talmud Bavli, please.

Comment: @YehudaW I haven't looked it up. You don't have a Mishna? Try Sefaria for instance.